# What is the meaning of a warning "Vote to delete this post?" when deleting an answer.

Tags: bug, warning, vote-to-delete

I get a warning "Vote to delete this post?" when deleting an answer. What does *vote* mean? and What are the implications if I click on <kbd>OK</kbd>?. Can anyone help explain it to me?

Comment: As a supplement of the normal [FAQ] site, there's a series of [FAQ-questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7931/193906) here on [metase]. These will often answer common questions in more detail than the regular [FAQ]. To search for posts in the Q&A-type FAQ, you can search for posts with the [meta-tag:faq]-tag by including '`[faq]`' in your search query (e.g. [`how does deleting work [faq]`](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=how+does+deleting+work+%5Bfaq%5D)) or you can search Google: [`how does deleting work faq site:meta.stackoverflow.com`](http://goo.gl/I7xp5)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per [Moderator tools privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/moderator-tools) delete link is visible to any 10K+ users. They can't delete directly. They have to *vote to delete* to delete the post. So they get this message when click on delete link:

> Vote to delete this post?

While diamond moderators or OP (of the post) can directly delete it. So this message should not be shown. Instead the should be something like this:

> Are you sure? Do you want to delete this post?

So probably this is a bug.

I don't know what message do diamond moderators get when they click on delete link.

> What are the implications if I choose "OK"?

Simply look at this [FAQ of deleting post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221/187824)

Answer (score 0):

Currently, nothing undoable happens if you delete your own answer:

> Self-deleted answers can be viewed, edited, and undeleted by their original authors.

See the [faq](/questions/tagged/faq)-post [How does deleting work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5222/193906) for more info.

---

I'm not sure why it says "*Vote to delete post?*" though. I think it's a bit misleading.

I would say it should instead say something like "*Are you sure you want to delete this answer?*" and possibly link to the [deletion-part of the FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5222/193906).

If you think this should be changed, you can search to check if this has already been suggested. If not, you can post a suggestion question with the [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) tag.